# How do I deal with a forced close message on Android?

Tags: android

I am having trouble debugging my app that causes a pop-up "Forced close" message every time I try to use my android app. How can I go around it ?

Answer (score 3):

Usually "force close" means that you are getting an Exception that you are not handling / expecting.

Use logcat to check what is happing with your app and try to fix it.

You can use log cat like this:

- .\adb.exe logcat

If you are seeing to much info in the log you can filter the log with something like this:

- .\adb.exe logcat  ActivityManager:I YOUR_APP_TAG:D *:S

I don't use Eclipse so I don't know if by default eclipse console will show you what is happening with your application.

Hope it helps, good luck

Answer (score 0):

"Forced close" means the program crashed. You need to determine why it crashed and fix it.